# Mini Cart doesn't include fees

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using very sιmple code to add fees in woocommerce cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'modify_cart_price', 13, 1);
function modify_cart_price( $cart_obj ) {
    $cart_obj->add_fee('Fee Description', 10);
}
```

the code works as expected in cart and checkout, however it doesn't work in standard woocommerce minicart. The fee is nowhere displayed and the cart total doesn't include it. Is there a seperate hook for the minicart or any other solution to the problem?

Comment: I'd start by comparing what happens in the `cart-totals.php` and `mini-cart.php` template files. The former appears to execute a lot more specific & detailed hooks, than the latter.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for guiding me to the right direction. I was able to solve the problem by modifying mini-cart.php as a theme override. Although now the behavior is expected i was wondering, is there not another way of achieving this? maybe with a hook?